# MYSQL Finding server with failed status

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have sql table with following columns `id` as `PK`, `ip`, `check_type` `check_status`:

```
id      ip             check_type    check_status
1       10.10.10.10    check1        FAIL
2       10.10.10.10    check2        PASS
3       10.10.10.11    check1        PASS
4       10.10.10.11    check2        PASS
```

I want only the `ips` which have `Failed Check1 and Passed Check2` from the table.
So, from above example my output should be `10.10.10.10`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  (ip)
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table1 b
  ON a.ip = b.ip
WHERE a.check_status = 'FAIL'
AND a.check_type = 'check1'
AND b.check_status = 'PASS'
AND b.check_type = 'check2';
```

I am getting an error

> column ip is ambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  (a.ip)
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table1 b
  ON a.ip = b.ip
WHERE a.check_status = 'FAIL'
AND a.check_type = 'check1'
AND b.check_status = 'PASS'
AND b.check_type = 'check2';
```

This will work

Your are selecting ip that is in both a and b so it is giving error so when you write a.ip or b.ip it will work fine

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ip
FROM table1
GROUP BY ip
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN check_type = 'check1' AND check_status = 'FAIL'
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN check_type = 'check2' AND check_status = 'PASS'
                THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Another, slighty more elegant, way which should work on MySQL:

```
SELECT ip
FROM table1
WHERE (check_type, check_status) IN (('check1', 'FAIL'), ('check2', 'PASS'))
GROUP BY ip
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT check_type, check_status) = 2;
```

Here is a [**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd22b4/9) of the second query, courtesy of @MKhalid

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I figured out that the query can be written with the multi-column `WHERE IN` syntax, q.v. my updated answer.